# JavaScript to reload page if it is in bfcache

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put together a script for the browser to decide if the page it is loading comes from bfcache or from the server.  I'm 99% sure bfcache is the issue, because all the other problems I've seen of this nature cite bfcache as the issue.

This is relevant because the bfcache page "freezes" the state of the JavaScript on a website I'm working on (I didn't write those scripts, I'm a JavaScript amateur), and if you use the back button to get back to the page, the scripts don't work.  They work fine, though, if you hit the refresh button.

This is my attempt at solving this issue:

```
<body onload="noBFC()" onpageshow="checkCache()">
// Lots of HTML content

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkCache(){
        if (cached == true){
            location.reload(true);}
    };

    var cached = "";

    function noBFC(){
        cacheCheck = false;
    };

    window.onunload() {
        cacheCheck = true;
    };
</script>
```

The rationale being, whenever the user navigates away from the page, `window.onunload()` will set the variable `cached` to boolean "true", to indicate that it has been cached by bfcache.

Then, whenever the page is shown again with `onpageshow`, the script checks that variable.  If it's "true", it forces a page reload with the value of `cached` set to "false".

Is there something easy I missed syntactically, or is this just not a workable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try appending a random query to the location string.

```
window.location = location.href + '?random=' + 1234;
```

Comment: You mean, instead of what I've tried, or in addition to it?

Comment: So I have tried to implement this solution, using:

   onload="noBFC()"

Then, generating a random number.  I cannot figure out how to get this script to run just once.  I tried saying:

    if (window.location == myurl.com){//Runs this script}

But that just doesn't work at all.